# for loop over column names in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

I am trying to loop each selected column to get the table().
Many thanks in advance.

```
  my.df <- mtcars[,c(2:5)]
colnames(my.df) <- c("A.1", "A.2", "A.3", "A.4")

nam <- NULL; my.tables <- NULL
for(i in 1:4) { 
  nam[i] <- paste("A.", i, sep = "")
  my.tables[i] <- table(my.df$nam[i])
}
nam
my.tables
```

Expected Answer

```
 table(my.df$A.1)....table(my.df$A.4)
```

Comment: `lapply(my.df, table)`?

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to set a for loop using the column name in this case my.df$A.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `for` loop solution.

```
# reserve space for the variables beforehand
nam <- character(4)
my.tables <- vector("list", length = 4)
for(i in 1:4) {
  nam[i] <- paste0("A.", i)
  my.tables[[i]] <- table(my.df[[ nam[i] ]])
}
nam
my.tables
```

The only difference from the loop's results are the list members' names. The `lapply` loop way assigns names.

```
my.tables2 <- lapply(my.df, table)
all.equal(my.tables, my.tables2)
#[1] "names for current but not for target"
```

Like this you can access the results in any of the following equivalent ways.

```
my.tables2$A.1
my.tables2[["A.1"]]
my.tables2[[1]]
```

Whereas without the names attribute assigned, only by list member number.

```
my.tables[[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution using the `purrr` package:

```
my.tables <- purrr::map(mtcars[, c(2:5)], table)
```